# Why does nth-child prevent a:hover style working?

Tags: css, transform

I have a simple list of images, styled to look like polaroid images.

Each image is rotated.

```
a.polaroid {
   transform: rotate(-2deg);
}
```

A scale transform is used on hover.

```
a.polaroid:hover {
   transform: scale(1.15);
}
```

All is well at this point.

However, some additional styling is added to alter the default rotation for certain images.
I.e. all even images, every 3rd image etc.

```
/* Rotate all even images 2 degrees */
li:nth-child(even) a.polaroid {
   transform: rotate(1deg); 
}

/* Cancel rotation for every 3rd image */
li:nth-child(3n) a.polaroid {
   transform: none;
}
```

For some reason, adding these styles prevents the hover style applying for any image that is targeted by these styles. I.e. every even image and every 3rd image.

Any idea why???

Please see associated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/46sdd/

Updated fiddle with solution is here: http://jsfiddle.net/46sdd/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selector [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity) (see also, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)) - your `a.polaroid:hover` is not specific enough to override `li:nth-child(3n) a.polaroid`. The solution is to add the necessary specifics to former, so they match, and move the `:hover` selector below `:nth-child` ones:

```
li:nth-child(3n) a.polaroid
li a.polaroid:hover
```